# For what reason do I need permission "android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA"

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm working on an old project of my company and want to look up the manifest for unused components. Doing this I found the permission `android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA` in manifest file, but I don't know for what reason the app does need it.

Every documentation I found says that this permission "Allows an application to write (but not read) the owner's data." That's okay, but I want to know for what API / method I need the permission so I can look up the existing code, if I need it!

Thank you for your help!

Greetings,
Jamic

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the permission nowadays, the only reference I found is in some old android versions' [contact provider](http://androidxref.com/1.6/xref/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider.java#1995); the permission was [removed in version 9](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/9/changes/android.Manifest.permission.html).

Comment: In addition, `WRITE_PROFILE` is the (roughly) equivalent permission now. May have better luck searching for that.